# TeX files not compiling after moving from TeXMaker to TeXShop

Tags: pdftex

I moved from my old Mac where I was using TeXMaker to the new one where I am using TeXShop.However, some old files I haven't used in the last 10 years are not compiling. These are simple beamer files. When I try to compile it shows the following in the console:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./matching problem presentation.tex/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: getwd: Operation not permitted

I would be really glad if someone could help with this.